# Is there a one-line version of "add to array if not nil, otherwise don't bother"?

Tags: swift

Say I have an array of `Int`s.

```
var nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
var maybeNum: Int?
nums.append(maybeNum)
```

But this results in an error. Do I really have to check if it has a value, and only insert it if it does?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following extension:

```
extension Array {
    public mutating func append(_ newElement: Element?) {
        if let element = newElement {
            self.append(element)
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can still use the original `append` method. When appending a non-optional element, the regular method will be used. When appending an optional element, this method will be used and the element will only be appended when it is not nil.

Answer (score 10):

Use map(_:) with optional binding, i.e. will only append when maybeNum is not nil:

```
var nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
var maybeNum: Int?
maybeNum.map { nums.append($0) }
```

Apple documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to 'unwrap' `maybeNum` whose type is `Int?`.
After unwraing, `num`'s type is `Int` which can be appened to `nums: [Int]`

```
if let num = maybeNum {
    nums.append(num)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite late to this question, but there is an option as well by using `compactMap()`. This method will call the function you pass to it in every element of the array, and then exclude *null* elements from the result. So, by passing a function that just return the element, you can transform an array of type `[Int?]` into `[Int]`.

```
let onlyNumbers = [1, 2, 3, nil, 4].compactMap { $0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an Array extension

```
extension Array {
    mutating func compactAppend(_ element: Element?) {
        if let element = element {
            self.append(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var optionalElement: Int?
myArray.compactAppend(optionalElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make nums be an array of optional Ints instead.

```
var nums = [Int?]()
nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
var maybeNum: Int?
nums.append(maybeNum)
```

However, there is now a nil element inside of the array.

The other option would be:

```
var nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
var maybeNum: Int?
if maybeNum != nil {nums.append(maybeNum!)}
```

Which does what you wanted in one line.

Answer (score -1):

You could write an extension like this:

```
extension ExtensibleCollectionType {
    mutating func maybeAppend(optional: Self.Generator.Element?) {
        if let x = optional {
            self.append(x)
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var maybeNumber: Int? 
self.maybeAppend(maybeNumber)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the combination of `+=` and `compactMap()` instead of `append()`.

```
    nums += [maybeNum].compactMap { $0 }
```

```
    var nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    let maybeNum: Int? = nil
    nums += [maybeNum].compactMap { $0 }
    print(nums)
    // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

```
    var nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    let maybeNum: Int? = 6
    nums += [maybeNum].compactMap { $0 }
    print(nums)
    // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
```

Yon can also use `+=` to append non-optional Int.

```
    var nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    
    let maybeNum: Int? = 6
    let probablyNum: Int? = nil
    
    let definitelyNum: Int = 7
    let surelyNum: Int = 8
    
    nums += [maybeNum].compactMap { $0 }
    nums += [probablyNum].compactMap { $0 }
    
    nums += [definitelyNum]
    nums.append(surelyNum)
    
    print(nums)
    // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8]
```